# Python with Visual Studio Code - How to deactive "Python Experimental"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am programming python 3 with Microsoft Code.

When I press "F5" to start the programm I always get a menu with the following selection:

- Python
- Python Experimental
- More
  to select the execution environment.

However, I directly want standard python to be run, when pressing F5.

I have googled a lot and already checked the configuration of Microsoft Code (there is only one python installed and selected) but did not find a switch to switch "Experimental" off.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me once. Seems like the Python Debug Configurations didnt load correctly.
After reselecting my Interpreter I was able to select the Debug Configuration "Python: Current File" again and run it without prompting me to select a Config.